# Why can an `ifstream` be opened both for reading and writing?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I've seen an interesting piece of code today:

```
ifstream fil;

fil.open( "ini.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out );
```

I was just about to rant about its brokenness, but to my astonishement I saw that cppreference.com apparently thinks this is correct:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

> mode  -   specifies stream open mode. It is bitmask type, the following constants are defined:
>
> - in: open for reading
> - out: open for writing

How can an `ifstream`, which, as far as I understand is an INPUT file stream, be opened both for reading and writing?

Shouldn't it necessarily be `fstream` instead of `ifstream`?

Comment: You need `std::fstream` for this purpose.

Comment: @user0042 Fine; so why does cppreference list both `std::ios::in` AND `std::ios::out` under IFSTREAM::open??

Comment: What would you expect? An exception?

Comment: @gaazkam Even if you can open a file for both read, and write, with which methods defined in `std::ifstream`, do you expect to write any data?

Comment: Undid the downvote.  It's a legitimate question

Comment: @Joe - You didn't "undo" anything. The downvote still stands. It's someones valid opinion of this question. Your opinion differs, but it doesn't unmake the other persons opinion.

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest with no one there to hear, did it really fall? Or in other words: If you open an `istream` for writing, but it has no API for writing, can you really write to it?

Comment: Interesting question, but the title is confusing, makes people tend to answer "fstream".

Comment: @SummerFang So how should I title this question instead?

Comment: For me 'why' instead of ’how’ :) But personal opinion

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, I managed to figure out how opinions work.  I'm speaking numerically

Comment: @Joe - It did not undo that either. The OP didn't gain +15, but +13. You didn't change anything numerically. Get off the habit of reactive voting. Plenty of very bad questions stay on SO because of it. If you think it's good, vote up, if you do not, don't. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @StoryTeller I voted it up because it was a legitimate question as I stated.   My "valid opinion" was that the downvote was petty.  Sorry that upset you

Comment: @Joe - That wasn't your stated opinion. Your explicitly stated you voted reactively. Your change in story now, is only because you *hope* to "upset" me, by being "clever".

Comment: @StoryTeller  Yeah you caught on to my clever plan.  Curses, foiled again.

Comment: @gaazkam - your question title and question was just fine.  The ability to do things like this reveals the near pointlessness of even having ifstream and ofstream.  The only thing they really "buy" you from fstream is a default argument in the constructor/open functions.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ifstream` is like a handle over a `std::basic_filebuf`. You can even access that buffer from the handle with a call to `std::basic_ifstream::rdbuf`.

You can steal that buffer from the handle, and assign it to another (I won't go into *how* it's done). And here's the interesting thing. You can move that very buffer from an `ifstream` to an `ofstream`. And that requires being able to open the buffer for writing. As such, the very same reference page you linked says this:

> Effectively calls `rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | ios_base::in)`

This is a convenience function to avoid manipulating the buffer itself later.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `fstream`:

```
fstream file("input.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
int data;

file >> data;
file << data +1;

file.close();
```

Comment: The question already states that they know it should be fstream.  They're asking why does it work at all with ifstream.